# Можно ли добавить таймер в оператор switch?

Tags: c#

```js
  switch (tmnmru) {
    case "DAY":

      if (targetHourOfDay != nowHour) {
        //Разница между часами
        int waitDay = (nowDayOfWeek < targetDayOfWeek) ? targetDayOfWeek - nowDayOfWeek : (7 - nowDayOfWeek) + targetDayOfWeek;
        int waithour = (nowHour < targetHourOfDay) ? targetHourOfDay - nowHour : (24 - nowHour) + targetHourOfDay;
        int waitMinute = (nowMinute < targetMinuteOfHour) ? targetMinuteOfHour - nowMinute : (60 - nowMinute) + targetMinuteOfHour;
        Console.WriteLine(dbStr);
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(waitDay).AddHours(waithour).AddMinutes(waitMinute);
        Console.WriteLine("Таймер должен запуститься в : {0} ", startTime.ToString());

        // Узнаем разницу в миллисекундах, оставшуюся до запуска

        double waitTime_ms = (startTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine("До запуска осталось: {0} мc.", waitTime_ms);
        MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();

        myTimer.Interval = waitTime_ms;
        myTimer.s_id = Convert.ToString(row["shedule_id"]);
        myTimer.alg = Convert.ToString(row["meta_cod"]);
        myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
        myTimer.AutoReset = true;
        myTimer.datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime);
        myTimer.Enabled = true;



      }
      break;

    case "HOUR":

      if ((targetMinuteOfHour != nowMinute) || (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(3)))) {

        //Посчитаем разницу между минутами
        int waitMinute = (nowMinute < targetMinuteOfHour) ? targetMinuteOfHour - nowMinute : (60 - nowMinute) + targetMinuteOfHour;
        int waitDay = (nowDayOfWeek < targetDayOfWeek) ? targetDayOfWeek - nowDayOfWeek : (7 - nowDayOfWeek) + targetDayOfWeek;
        int waithour = (nowHour < targetHourOfDay) ? targetHourOfDay - nowHour : (24 - nowHour) + targetHourOfDay;
        Console.WriteLine(dbStr + " " + "Minute");


        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(waitDay).AddHours(waithour).AddMinutes(waitMinute);
        Console.WriteLine("Таймер должен запуститься в : {0} ", startTime.ToString());

        // Узнаем разницу в миллисекундах, оставшуюся до запуска

        double waitTime_ms = (startTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("До запуска осталось: {0} мc.", waitTime_ms);
        MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();

        myTimer.Interval = waitTime_ms;
        myTimer.s_id = Convert.ToString(row["shedule_id"]);
        myTimer.alg = Convert.ToString(row["meta_cod"]);
        myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
        myTimer.AutoReset = true;
        myTimer.datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime);
        myTimer.Enabled = true;


      }

      break;

    case "WEEK":

      if ((targetDayOfWeek != nowDayOfWeek) || (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(2)))) {
        //DateTime dtDayandHour = Convert.ToDateTime(splitStr);
        //  double DayandHour = Convert.ToDouble(dtDayandHour);
        // Console.WriteLine("интервал: {0}", DayandHour);
        // Посчитаем разницу между днями 
        int waithour = (nowHour < targetHourOfDay) ? targetHourOfDay - nowHour : (24 - nowHour) + targetHourOfDay;
        Console.WriteLine(waithour);
        int waitDay = (nowDayOfWeek < targetDayOfWeek) ? targetDayOfWeek - nowDayOfWeek : (7 - nowDayOfWeek) + targetDayOfWeek;
        Console.WriteLine(dbStr + " " + "Day and hour");

        // Вычислим время запуска
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(waitDay).AddHours(targetHourOfDay);
        Console.WriteLine("Таймер должен запуститься в : {0} ", startTime.ToString());

        // Узнаем разницу в миллисекундах, оставшуюся до запуска

        double waitTime_ms = (startTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine("До запуска осталось: {0} мс.", waitTime_ms);
        MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();

        myTimer.Interval = waitTime_ms;
        myTimer.s_id = Convert.ToString(row["shedule_id"]);
        myTimer.alg = Convert.ToString(row["meta_cod"]);
        myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
        myTimer.AutoReset = true;
        myTimer.datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime);
        myTimer.Enabled = true;


      }

      break;
```

Есть таймер, которая записывает данные в таблицу. Есть 3 вида таймера: первый таймер работает каждую неделю, второй работает каждый день , третий работает каждую час?

Comment: // Узнаем разницу в миллисекундах, оставшуюся до запуска
      double waitTime_ms = (startTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes;
Интервал разве не в миллисекнудах? А вы берете то минуты, то секунды. Ни одного попадания.

Comment: все заработало) нужно просто `TotalMinutes`

Comment: @Monk Как можно сделать интервал таймера каждый час, если в CASE = `DAY` ?

Comment: @Monk у меня таймер запускается в каждую неделю. А мне надо сделать так, чтобы я включил таймер, а потом он тикал каждый час

Comment: вы где то перемудрили, но я не понимаю, чего вы добиваетесь. Таймеры, запускающие таймеры - подозрительное поведение.

Comment: @Monk  как сделать интервал в моём случае?

Comment: По возможности - опишите, что вы пытаетесь сделать, используя таймеры. Например - мне нужен таймер, чтобы через N часов после события M выполнить метод Do. Чем подробнее опишите, тем проще будет помочь.

Comment: Объясните лучше на словах, пока не очень понятно.

Comment: @VladD изменил вопрос)

Comment: @propro17: А в чём вопрос теперь? «_Есть 3 вида таймера: первый таймер работает каждую неделю, второй работает каждый день , третий работает каждую час?_» — а вопрос в чём?